# Image won't change after changing the value in ts file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a model that has an enum as one of it's attributes.
I want to display an image accordingly, so, if the attribute (`Category`) is music, I want to display a music image for example.

This is my `.ts` file:

```
export class GoalCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() goal: Goal;
  private iconName: string = "default";
  imgSrc: string = `/assets/category-icons/${this.iconName}.png`;

  private categories: string[] = Object.values(Category);
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.goal.category != null && this.categories.includes(this.goal.category)) {
        this.iconName = this.goal.category
    }
  }

}
```

I set my `iconName` as default, in case I don't have a category attribute (it is optional in the model).

The problem is that my `.html` file of won't change accordingly and it remains of `default.png` although I do have a category chosen.

This is my `.html` file:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-row class="goal-card-container">
      <ion-avatar class="goal-card-category-img" style="background-color: aquamarine; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        <ion-img [src]="imgSrc" style="width: 90%; height: 90%;"></ion-img>
      </ion-avatar>
      <div class="goal-info-container">
        <ion-label class="goal-title-name">{{ goal.title }}</ion-label>
      </div>

      <a class="details-button"></a>
  </ion-row>
</ion-card>
```

My guess is that `iconName` is being updated only after the page is already display, but I thought that `[src]` should bind the source to `imgSrc`, so when it changes, it should refresh the page, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the imgSrc on the ngOnInit like this:

```
export class GoalCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() goal: Goal;
  private iconName: string = "default";
  imgSrc: string = `/assets/category-icons/${this.iconName}.png`;

  private categories: string[] = Object.values(Category);
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.goal.category != null && this.categories.includes(this.goal.category)) {
        this.iconName = this.goal.category;
        this.imgSrc = `/assets/category-icons/${this.iconName}.png`;
    }
  }

}
```

Or, you can use goal [`getter and setter`](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/) to update the `imgSrc` each time the `goal` value change, which will be a more robust solution:

```
export class GoalCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() 
  set goal(goal: Goal) {
      this.goal = goal;
      if(this.goal.category != null && this.categories.includes(this.goal.category)) {
        this.iconName = this.goal.category;
        this.imgSrc = `/assets/category-icons/${this.iconName}.png`;
      }
  }

  private iconName: string = "default";
  private _goal: Goal;

  imgSrc: string = `/assets/category-icons/${this.iconName}.png`;

  private categories: string[] = Object.values(Category);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, It did work. I thought that imgSrc updates when iconName updates, I guess it wasn't. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnDoah Alternative you can use setters in typescript to get a more robust solution. Check out my update to get more info.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a look at it.